# DNS nameservers, can I set it to anything I like?

Tags: domain-name-system

My domain auto-renewed on 15/12/19 and suddenly web/mail etc failed.
I'm currently getting no NS set on my domain, even though my dashboard says it's set:

```
dig youtoggle.com NS +short
whois reports NS set:
whois youtoggle.com | grep NS
Name Server: NS-CLOUD-A1.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
Name Server: NS-CLOUD-A2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
Name Server: NS-CLOUD-A3.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
Name Server: NS-CLOUD-A4.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
nslookup fails:
nslookup youtoggle.com
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 8.8.8.8, trying next server
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 8.8.4.4, trying next server
```

I'm baffled, my DNS-fu is mild. 
Hilariously, no-one can recall setting the NS to google. Only setting up the website on Wix. Surely this couldn't be done without registrar access?
Is it possible Wix set DNSSEC? Help :(

Comment: After hassling my registrar for 16 hours it seems there was something they fixed on their side. Won't tell me what or apologise for the stress and downtime but there you go.

Comment: whois is not a tool to debug DNS problems. you should use `dig` or the inferior `nslookup` but starting by querying authoritative nameservers (those of the parent zone) before recursive ones (and they exist others than Google's ones). you shouldn't wait for last time to renew a domain, some registrars may put the domain on hold (hence not resolving) as soon as you hit expiration. and if you are not satisfied with your registrar, you can transfer your domain to another one, without loosing any existing time before expiration.